# Dual boot Ubuntu (14.04) with Windows 10

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, system-installation, windows, preinstallation

I have a Windows 8 system and was about to install Ubuntu 14.04 in dual boot mode, when I heard about Windows 10 releasing. Now that the Windows 10 has rolled out, I would like to know whether doing the same steps as for Windows 8 would install it. I would wait until somebody else has tried it out and posted it on the internet, but I'm somewhat out of time to wait. Will it be risky trying it out so soon, or does anyone know about what would work?

Comment: It is not released, not until Fall. But various testing, alpha, beta versions are out. Windows 10 Dual boot on Toshiba works - sudodus
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2246751&p=13137869#post13137869 Should be about the same as Windows 8 http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system

Comment: Assuming that they don't come out for a new boot system to replace EFI for windows 10 you should be ok doing dual boot from the way you may be doing it on windows 8. However, this is not know yet even with alpha, beta versions yet. Because the purpose of windows 10 is for the same kernel to run on all devices, thus allowing for better continuity. Until it actually launches you won't know for sure.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this would be about a new (unreleased) Windows installation interfering with an already existing Windows installation. It has nothing to do with Ubuntu.

Comment: @LiveWireBT: why vote to close?  It's about dual-boot with a Windows system that more then one person on this site currently is running...  And it works!  (See answer)

Comment: @Fabby You're assuming BIOS boot, e.g. what ever is in the MBR takes over booting. There is nothing wrong with that, but OEM installations of Windows 8 are UEFI. In that case the last installation of Windows would overwrite contents in from previous installation in `\EFI\Microsoft` on the ESP (where boot configuration and bootloader of Windows are stored). Linux EFI loaders in other directories wouldn't be affected, which is why I think that this question is only about Windows.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right about that!  Delete answer?

Comment: I realize this question is kind of old, but this question is very on-topic- people have problems when updating Windows 8.1 to Windows 10, because Windows 10 does sometimes mess up the boot partition, which affects Ubuntu (and all other OSes on the system) if things aren't done right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been dual-booting Windows 10 preview for 3 months now: no problems whatsoever in BIOS mode...  (No UEFI here!)

However, I have 2 hard drives in my machine and change the boot order to boot from one hard drive or the other one.  I did run for a week or so from one hard drive, but something got screwed up, so I reverted to booting from 2 hard drives again...

And as to waiting: you can always wait for the new CPU, the new Windows, the new GPU, ...  If you're out of time to wait, get a system with Windows 8 and dual boot that as Microsoft has announced that anyone with a Windows 8 system can upgrade for free within one year...

Answer (score 0):

I'm dual booting them right now- I just answered my own question detailing the process. This was specific to my firmware, but the general principles will appy. The most important thing is to make sure you do everything in UEFI if you have UEFI firmware, or everything for BIOS if you have BIOS firmware. Mixing methods is where things usually start to fail. (If you have UEFI firmware and want to use a legacy boot mode, treat it as BIOS, and keep your fingers crossed). See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/666631/how-can-i-dual-boot-windows-10-and-ubuntu-on-a-uefi-hp-notebook).

Comment: Your link is broken.  Should be this I think: http://askubuntu.com/questions/666631/how-can-i-dual-boot-windows-10-and-ubuntu-on-a-uefi-hp-notebook

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I think I fixed it, but I'm on mobile, so it's hard to tell :P

Comment: Yeah, it's good now.  Nice write up too.

Comment: Thank you. I was worried it was too long and too specific, but hopefully it will help others avoid the messes I made following older answers to similar questions.