# Installing ubuntu on window 10

Tags: dual-boot

am using intel(R) celeron(R) CPU N2840 @2.16Hz 2.16Hz 
WITH 4.00GB RAM hw can i partiton it and be using it with ubuntu without crashing my system on windows 10

Answer (score 0):

There are many tutorials out there on Internet like [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot), [this](http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/dual-boot-ubuntu-15-04-14-10-and-windows-10-8-1-8-step-by-step-tutorial-with-screenshots), [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/666631/how-can-i-dual-boot-windows-10-and-ubuntu-on-a-uefi-hp-notebook),and many more. It's simply a matter of searching.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.