# Windows 10 and Ubuntu 14.04 (LTS) dual booting issues

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I have a [HP envy 15-j048tx](http://support.hp.com/us-en/product/HP-ENVY-15-Notebook-PC-series/5354982/model/5448971) laptop with UEFI on which I'm having trouble installing Ubuntu 14.04 LTS alongside Windows 10.

I have read  [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/666631/how-can-i-dual-boot-windows-10-and-ubuntu-on-a-uefi-hp-notebook) as well as [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation/343370#343370),but I don't seem to understand from a UEFI settings perspective.

The first picture shows the current UEFI settings. [image]

As you can see Ubuntu does not detect Windows 10 and does not even allow me to install it on a different 100 GB partition which I created using the Disk Management utility.

If I choose the option "Something Else" Ubuntu does not "See" the partition that I created on Windows.

So far I have tried disabling secure boot in UEFI and disabling fast start up and shutting it down.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

First boot in to Windows 10, and open disk management and check whether the partitions are **dynamic**. Linux cannot be installed on a dynamic disk. (Screenshot would help)

Then check whether you have a EFI partition (**vFat**) around 100mb. That means you installed Windows in EFI mode.

If the Windows installtion is EFI, then you should also boot your Ubuntu Live Media in EFI mode, if not the legacy bios mode.

Then continue with the Ubuntu installtion as usual.

REFERENCES:

[Decide whether you want to install in UEFI mode or Bios mode.](http://www.linuxdeveloper.space/fix-partition-table-issues-win-linux/)

Answer (score 1):

Some partitions may still to be mounted because Windows seems to be in hibernation mode.

So you first have to **boot into Windows** and **disable hibernation** and **Fast Boot** in Windows.

Open **command prompt as administrator** and execute :

```
powercfg /h off
```

Then open the the **old** version (not the modern) of **Windows Control Panel**.

Select **Energy Settings** - enable **show hidden settings** - **uncheck Fast Boot**.

After having done this - **shutdown** the machine **completely** - do **NOT reboot** !

Start the computer and select the **UEFI Ubuntu USB drive option** to boot from.

Select **Try Ubuntu without installing** - start the installer - choose **Something else**.

Install Ubuntu to the unallocated (free) space which you created in Windows before.

After installation is finished, boot into BIOS and select **Ubuntu** to be the **default OS**.

Comment: Hi Looks like I have destroyed the MBR,Partition table etc..You may close this post. I would like to open a new one. I'm really sorry to take so much of your time.

Comment: @alok : It is better when you edit and update your question with new information - maybe I can help you further with this ! :)

Comment: I think I was posting this question http://askubuntu.com/questions/700839/ubuntu-14-04-installation-attempt-destroys-windows-10  when you wrote this. Sorry about that.

Comment: Why "Try Ubuntu" and then manually start the installer? That should be the same as directly clicking on "Install Ubuntu"...

Comment: @ByteCommander : Because of for whatever reasons sometimes this does and did not work for many users. :)

Answer (score 0):

cl-netbox and reversiblean have both provided useful suggestions. Some more points I'd like to make:

- You may want to read [my page on installing Linux on EFI systems](http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-uefi/), which provides general tips on how to install Linux on EFI-based systems
- [The Ubuntu community wiki entry on UEFI](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) is a bit disjointed, but is the most Ubuntu-specific introduction to EFI and its issues.
- Most people report that the "Install Alongside" option is absent on EFI-based systems. I don't know the cause. (It could be the hibernation and Fast Startup issues that cl-netbox describes; I've never looked into it.) In any event, you may need to use the "Something Else" option, as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation), among other places.
- If you get to the "Something Else" option and it shows that the disk is blank (unpartitioned), when in fact you know it contains partitions, then that indicates a problem with the partition table. There can be many causes for this problem, so I'm reluctant to offer advice without more information. Showing the output of `sudo parted -l`, `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda`, `sudo sgdisk -v /dev/sda`, and `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda` may be helpful. Edit your question to provide this information or post it to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com/) and post the URL to your output here. (Do not try to cram the output into a comment; it won't fit and the formatting will be lost, making it nearly illegible.)