# Ubuntu 14.04 installation attempt destroys Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

A few hours ago I was trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 along side Windows on a UEFI Laptop by following the steps given [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/700734/windows-10-and-ubuntu-14-04-lts-dual-booting-issues) without any success.

I'm pretty sure I would have succeeded had I followed the steps correctly and not messed around with the installation options.

Here's what I did.I playfully chose LVM (without knowing what it is) and clicked 'next'which has now corrupted the MBR or the Partition table (all these are wild guesses,I really don't know what has gone wrong).

I suspected something fishy and I decided to reboot (abandoning the installation) and I tried booting from the Laptop HDD (to test if windows boots or not) instead of the USB stick (which holds Ubuntu boot file) and to my surprise I don't see windows booting at all.

Instead its booting from the USB stick asking me to either try Ubuntu or install it.

The only option for me is to boot from a live USB stick (which is how I'm using my computer right now and writing this!).

My Laptop has got a 1 TB HDD and this is what `fdisk -l | more`outputs.
[image]

gparted shows the following .

[image]

Please could you guide me step by step on how to "rescue" windows 10 from a live Ubuntu Stick.

Edit: The current output that I notice when trying to boot to windows 10 (after removing the USB stick) is "No Active Partition" (white writing with a black background)

Thank You

Comment: yes, you deleted windows, you need to reinstall windows from scratch (or backup). as such this is now a question of "how to install or restore a backup of windows" and is not about ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is what you selected, then you wiped the entire HDD.

[image]

You must now reinstall Windows 10.

There is a way to install Windows 10 from the Live Ubuntu but I don't know for sure it will work:

1. From GParted: Put a GPT partition table on your HDD.
2. Make a 8 - 10 GB FAT32 partition at the end of the HDD. Leave the remaining space unallocated.
3. Mount this new partition.
4. In the live distribuition, go to [Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO) and download Windows 10 ISO in the partition you created.
5. Extract the ISO (I don't know how you do that in a live distro) in the root of that partition so that you will get Windows folders like this:

[image]

6. Go to `efi` folder, then `boot` and checck if you have a `bootx64.efi` file there.
7. Restart PC, remove USB flashdrive and set it to boot from HDD. It may start Windows installation.
8. When formatting HDD for Windows, do not format the partition at the end that holds installation files! You will do that from Windows Disk Management after the installation is completed.

**Note:** In case this will work, it works for UEFI only!