# Can i install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10?

Tags: 14.04, windows, uefi, syslinux

I have a Lenovo laptop with Windows 10 on it. Is it possible to install any version of Ubuntu alongside Windows 10?

Answer (score 1):

Answering this question can be a bit longer. Based on what you are trying to achieve. You can Install Ubuntu on a Virtual Machine using built in `*Hyper-V* (If you have a PRO Edition of Win) Windows Feature,` *`VMWare Player (Free) or Oracle Virtual Box hypervisors`*. Again it depends on your goal.

Also you can install the Ubuntu as a native OS as well, if you are looking for a Dual Boot System. Downside will be ,since Ubuntu install its own bootloader in the system partition, if in case you want to get rid of it in future the you will have to Re-install the Entire OS (windows) after formatting the Drive.

Personally, I will recommend to have Ubuntu installed on the different HDD than the same windows have. You can read more about it on 
[How can I dual-boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu on a UEFI HP notebook?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/666631/how-can-i-dual-boot-windows-10-and-ubuntu-on-a-uefi-hp-notebook)