# Any known pitfalls when installing on windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

I have downloaded Ubuntu 15 (32 bit) on a flash drive, I migh burn it on a DVD too if necessary, and I have noticed the question asked in here five years ago,

[How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

-which has a very clear guide for installing in its answer, thank you for that!

**Windows 10 seems very invasive, are there any known issues for installing a clean version of Ubuntu without keeping Windows?**

edit: I do not want a dual boot, only Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing a clean installation of Ubuntu on a windows 10 pre-installed laptop, you might have some problems (listed below) which can be solved.

- **Secure boot** : you might need to disable secure boot in your BIOS menu before installing ubuntu.

  If you cant go to BIOS menu during startup, **fast start up** feature may be enabled. try disabling it in control panel>power options. and restart.

If you want to install **Ubuntu alongside Windows**, a detailed solution is given [here. How can I dual-boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu on a UEFI HP notebook?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/666631/how-can-i-dual-boot-windows-10-and-ubuntu-on-a-uefi-hp-notebook)

If you face any other problem, please ask specifically.

Comment: I can only make it to step 5 in the description from the link mentioned in my own post. It's a mastered, burnt DVD. Sadly, instead of  getting to point 6 in the instructions, "once you get a purple screen with a picture at the bottom", Windows 10 just boots itself back in. I have disabled Quick Boot and Network boot in the bios.The function Secure boot is not listed in the bios. I have Windows 10 32bit.

Comment: I have looked for: "Or, from Windows, hold the Shift key while selecting Restart. Go to Troubleshoot > Advanced Options: UEFI Firmware Settings.
Find the Secure Boot setting, and if possible, set it to Disabled. This option is usually in either the Security tab, the Boot tab, or the Authentication tab." but 'UEFI Firmware Settings' are not listed either. 
 p.s. I am not after a dual-boot, just a clean Ubuntu.

Comment: Might one of these be the right alternative in W10: Disable driver signature enforcement, or, Disable early launch anti-malware protection?

Comment: @Vivienne So I think you installed Ubuntu properly but cant boot into it. This may be because - For some reasons the GRUB time out is set to 0 and windows is set as default.

Comment: @Vivienne So I think you installed Ubuntu properly but cant boot into it. This may be because - For some reasons the GRUB time out is set to 0 and windows is set as default.   But you said you are not after duel-boot. So what I suggest is- Follow the same procedure once again , BUT in step 4, in GPARTED Partition Manager, Delete the Windows related partition. (Make backup of important files before). (And yes you can delete all the partitions if dont need any of them, which would be cleaner). and install ubuntu using this guide below  V|V

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation

Comment: Thank you very much for being so helpful in this! What I did was that I reset Windows 10, it actually took about 8 hours, then I made a fresh burned .iso for Ubuntu, again, and this time it worked! So far I am very, very enthusiastic about Linux Ubuntu! I did have a few very minor issues, it automatically set the Netbook to standby every 60 seconds during the installation,  but I didn't let it put me of as I could wake it up by pressing any key, then I had a couple of funny screens with all lines, but both issues have gone now. I might be  back with other questions eventually! Thanks again!