# Dual Boot Windows 10 Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, uefi, windows-10

I am trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 / 15.10 as a dual boot with my windows 10 education (on a dell xps 13). I have created my bootable USB drive using Rufus (GPT for EFI). I have disabled Secure Boot mode and Fast Startup, as described on many websites. As I boot on the drive, I have the choice between Try or Install Ubuntu. When I pick install, I go trough the language selection and the next screen (asking if I have any space, internet...). So far so good. But after that, nothing. Under the windows Installation type, the screen is blank. No drive appears. I don't even get to choose th installation option for Ubuntu to dual-boot alongside Windows Boot Manager as seen on other thread. If anyone could help with that, I have been struggling for hours now.

Comment: Here is the complete guide: [http://askubuntu.com/questions/666631/how-can-i-dual-boot-windows-10-and-ubuntu-on-a-uefi-hp-notebook](http://askubuntu.com/questions/666631/how-can-i-dual-boot-windows-10-and-ubuntu-on-a-uefi-hp-notebook)

Comment: Thanks but I have already seen this link and it does not answer my problem at all. I don't even get the chance to choose the installation type.

Comment: Refer http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation

Comment: Use UUI for creating LiveUSB, make partitions using Gparted and install using "Something else option"

Comment: Thanks but none of theses cases are actually helpful since I don't get anything for the installation type. I don't even get to chose the type of installation. I get straight to the windows where I am supposed to chose the partition (but nothing is available, not even free space).

Comment: I have tried with UUI and I actually have a partition created already (using diskmgmt). I don't get to chose the option, that's the frustrating part

Answer (score 1):

Try dropping to a shell or launching the "try before installing" option and opening a Terminal. Type `ls /dev/sd?` to see what disks are available. You should see at least two -- `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb`. One of these (typically `/dev/sda`) is your hard disk and the other (usually `/dev/sdb`) is the installation medium. (Unless you're booting from a CD, in which case you may see just `/dev/sda`.) From your description, I suspect that you'll see just `/dev/sda`, and that it will be your USB flash drive installation medium.

If I'm right, then the problem is that Ubuntu does not yet have drivers for your computer's disk controller -- or maybe your disk is unplugged or malfunctioning, but that should show up as an inability to boot Windows. I was under the impression that the Dell XPS 13 was supported, so this is surprising, if it's what you see. The solution to such problems is usually to use a more recent version of Ubuntu. You imply that you've tried both 14.04 and 15.10, and the latter is the most recent released version. You might try the [Xenial alpha](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/), though.

If you see both `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb`, then something else is going on. Posting a screen shot of the screen where you run into the problem may be informative. The output of `dmesg` may be helpful, too. (Type `dmesg > foo.txt`, post `foo.txt` to [a pastebin site,](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and post the URL to the document here.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The command /dev/sd? indeed only show /dev/sda. Since you're talking about drivers, it appears that I have an issue with the wireless drivers ("System" -> "Software and upadte" -> "Additional drivers") that froze Ubuntu. So should I wait for a newer version of Ubuntu or stop fighting and go to a VM ?

Comment: Wireless drivers are unrelated to your problem; it's likely that a disk controller driver is causing problems; or perhaps you've got bad hardware -- but that would likely manifest in Windows, too.