# installing ubuntu from a usb flash stick

Tags: usb, uefi

If I run ubuntu on a flash stick as the instructions say, then install it, where does it install to?  I have windows 10 and windows 7 on two different disks on a Asus computer with 16 GB memory, and want to run ubuntu on a different drive but not mess up the boot manager by installing it on one of the two disks internally. Someone explain the process of how to run ubuntu on a flash stick without messing up the boot manager on the uefi bios .

Comment: You allways have to make changes to the boot manager if you want to install and run more than one operating system. But you can allways just run the live version of Ubuntu from the USB stick without making any changes to your system.  Just boot from USB stick and use it.

Comment: Using live installer will make no changes to your system. IF you install and if UEFI, grub will create a small /EFI/ubuntu folder in the drive seen as sda for booting. If doing a full install to an external drive or larger flash drive then you have to copy the /EFI/ubuntu folder to that drive's ESP - efi system partition. If installing to one of Windows drives only use Windows to shrink NTFS partitions to make space for Linux partitions.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI and: http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to install the linux, which is what I am assuming you mean by "how to run ubuntu on a flash stick". You can look at this [link](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)
running linux on a usb stick wont effect bios you just interrupt the boot order for that one boot.

You will just need to interrupt your boot order for each boot you do this. A [quirky](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xzd73vS9WXo) video on how to do that.

You have two other options install linux onto one of your drives and and you can use the grub men to boot to either linux windows 7 or 10 anytime you boot.
here is a well thought out and well written guide for [windows 10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/666631/how-can-i-dual-boot-windows-10-and-ubuntu-on-a-uefi-hp-notebook)

Your other option depending on your need you can use a virtual machine, which would have no effect at all on your bios. And if you ever have any problems with it you can delete it. 
Here's [a link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142549/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-virtualbox) to see how to

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)