# UBUNTU 16.04 ERROR INSTALLING GRUB

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, grub-efi

My computer has Windows 10 installed, and when I try to install Ubuntu 16.04, it does not detect Windows 10, nor does it detect Windows 10 in my partitions list.

On the final step of the installation, it shows me this error.

```
grub-amd64-efi
```

Later, I run the LiveCD in "Try Ubuntu", and I paste this command in the terminal `sudo fixparts /dev/sda`, and `sudo fdisk -l` it does not work.

Help me please.

Comment: Your not alone. This has happened to me 3 times trying to install it on my MacBook Pro 2011. I am in the process of making another usb stick but I just think that this is a bug.

Comment: Did you turn off fast start up in Windows? Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: Yes I turn off fast start up in Windows

Comment: You are the second to report that error. I actually got full error, but it ran report ok and posted it to pastebin. I will report a bug to Boot-Repair.

Comment: Please boot to the live disk, open a Terminal window, and type the following commands: `sudo parted -l` and then `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda`. Copy-and-paste the complete output of both into your original question (edit it; do not try to paste it into a comment). You may also want to read [this question and answers.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)

Comment: This is sometimes caused by a bad burn of the install media. You might try burning it again. If it's a usb, be sure to wipe by making a new partition table (carefully)

Comment: I feel sad that this was downvoted. It's a good question, other than the title, which is very vague and could be improved to get this question more attention.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Comment: @DavidFoerster why is this a duplicated of that other, and don't tell me he's trying to install Ubuntu. He has messed up his installation already.

Comment: @MichaelHoffmann it got 5400 views. That's enough attention and nobody has "fixed" what you said it could be fixed, why don't you take a jab or better, close it as unclear.

Comment: @Braiam, MichaelHoffman answered it [LINK](http://askubuntu.com/questions/666631/how-can-i-dual-boot-windows-10-and-ubuntu-on-a-uefi-hp-notebook) for Windows 10, but specifically for case when you start with a blank drive Ubuntu is installed on first. Then Windows 10. I know my answer below is not full of detail, but gets the job done to a degree where someone can follow my steps and solve the case when you already have Windows 10 on the disk. I felt a motivated user would follow my links,read it, and come back to mine below. No? 19k views not statistically significant in my IMHO... Big Data!

Answer (score 5):

The solution for dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 is a bit tricky because it is somewhat hardware dependent.

See [this link for detailed answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/666632) and general explanation.
See [this link for the question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/666631/how-can-i-dual-boot-windows-10-and-ubuntu-on-a-uefi-hp-notebook) in case above link is invalid.

For my particular case, I have a [Samsung Series 9](http://www.samsung.com/us/computer/pcs/NP900X3A-A03US-specs) (2011) with Windows 10 installed. No other OS,but *my Windows 10 has **4 partitions*** (pictured below). This PC requires **F2** for setup, and no **F10**/**F11** options for boot menu. So the only configuration change in setup is "UEFI Boot Support" which limits the possible solutions to my problem.

The solution for me was to keep my Windows 10 install, and shrink partition to make room for Ubuntu 16.04 install.

First **press F2** for setup and **change boot priority** to make Primary **SATA HDD** and **Windows Boot Manager** *last*. Now it will allow me to boot into **USB Live**. Boot order in image is not correct so do what works for you, so it's okay if my ordering does not match your own.

[image: Note: boot order displayed is not correct!]

Use a 16.04 **USB Live**, and **start the installation** process.

Select "**Something Else**" when asked if you want to format whole disk in the "**Installation Type**" menu.

Now you are in the manual partition page for the mounted drives. I only have one drive which is called "**sda**"

[image: Example of my partition scheme with boot loader on /dev/sda]

Above Image Shows that I kept my Windows 10 install and made free space for the Ubuntu 16.04 which requires Ext4 file system.

After install restart, and **press F2** for setup and **change boot priority** to have primary **SATA HDD** and **Windows Boot Manager** at the top; respectively. This was not the end, but you should try it to see if it may be for your case. I had to go a few steps further.

Went back into **USB Live installation** and used a tool called **[Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)**

Redo Ubuntu 16.04 install, but change **Device for boot loader installion** from (pictured above):

> /dev/sda

to

> /dev/sda1

Restart and run **Boot-Repair** again with recommended option.

Final change setup boot priority to have SATA HDD and Windows Boot Manager at the top.

A combination of installing Grub and boot loader a few times allowed the installation to work, and allow Grub to be selected first.

Note in the image below that **sda1** is windows recovery, and **sda2** is Windows Boot Manager.

[image: sda2 is EFI file system or Windows Boot Manager when looking at disk utility in windows.]

**LAST STEP:** Match boot priority in setup as pictured below.

1. SATA HDD
2. Windows Boot Manager
3. ubuntu (**make it last**)

[image: Correct boot priority to allow Grub to boot first]

Below is a picture of disk utility software output (Disk Management) to show general partition scheme with **Windows 10**, **Ubuntu 14.04**, **Ubuntu 16.04**, and **Swap Area**. All 3 OS are accessible.

[image: Windows 10 disk management display of 3 OS win10, 14.04, and 16.04]

Below is my current GRUB, and yes it is a bit messy. I did advanced option on Boot-Repair to get Windows Boot Manager to be selected automatically. Current GRUB setup is a messy layout due to multiple install attempts and use of Boot-Repair utility

[image: Current GRUB setup with a messy layout due to multiple install attempts and use of Boot-Repair utility]

Answer (score 1):

I've had this issue since the beta version of ubuntu 16. I find that after the error shows up, if you reboot to the live cd and run boot-repair, the problem is fixed and ubuntu boots. To get windows booting again, all you need to do is run sudo update-grub

Comment: Did the boot-repair GUI come up? I was trying with kubuntu and didn't see it

Answer (score -1):

I have Windows 7, and after installing Ubuntu 16.04, I never saw the Windows option in GRUB.

Running this command worked for me:

```
sudo update-grub
```