# New installation of Ubuntu is stuck at loading screen

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation

I just installed Ubuntu alongside Windows on my Samsung Notebook 9 laptop. It stays at the loading screen after checking the drive when booting no matter what I do.

[image: loading screen]

Comment: Can you press "Esc" and add a picture of what's happening ?

Comment: Do you get grub menu? UEFI or BIOS install? Have you updated UEFI to latest available?  See this older question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/760102/ubuntu-16-04-error-installing-grub/762267#762267

Comment: Yes I did get grub menu UEFI install

Comment: Also at this loading screen i cant do anything but shutdown either press "ESC"