# Ubuntu Not Installing?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, software-installation

I've tried about 4 times now, with 14.04.1 LTS and 15.10. The install goes fine. No errors or anything like that or anything that would hint that something is going wrong. Whenever I try to install Ubuntu 14.04.1 or 15.10 alongside my Windows 10. When I reboot to get into the new "installation" it just boots my Windows and when I go to look at the partition I made (with special Windows EXT4 drivers) there is absolutely nothing there. Help?

Answer (score 0):

Im sure this is a duplicate of other related questions. Im mobile right now since ubuntu 16.04 update ruined my installation. But the there are one of two links that may help you.

Edit: 
**Installing ubuntu with uefi windows**
[Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

**How to dual boot ubuntu and windows**
[How can I dual-boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu on a UEFI HP notebook?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/666631/how-can-i-dual-boot-windows-10-and-ubuntu-on-a-uefi-hp-notebook)

Or

**Unable to boot windows after ubuntu install**
[Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)

Please post which one helps so the community can flag your post.

Before installing ubuntu next to windows (8+ and up) you should use windows to partition your hdd for ubuntu installation. Then choose the the parition space you created in windows using the ubuntu install. Turn off fast boot in bios and windows, and all should go well. Most likely fast boot is your issue and windows boot loader skips right past grub.

The reason your ext partitions will not display in windows is because Windows is incapable of of detecting Linux File systems and will not show up.