# Can't install Ubuntu 17.04 LTS

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, system-installation, 17.04

I am running Windows 10 and want to dual boot. I created a 60gb partition for Ubuntu using the preinstalled Windows partition editor. I was able to finish the installation, but when I pressed 'Restart Now' to finish the installation, it booted windows. I checked the ubuntu partition and it was empty. When I restarted, there was no grub. I tried to change the default os through the Windows control panel but there was only the windows option. What can I do?

Also:
I have found a very similar (but unanswered) question here [Ubuntu Not Installing?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760697/ubuntu-not-installing) but it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Did you follow the question's answer? What went wrong? What didn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was actually pretty simple:
I just had to disable and re-enable secure boot.
I am really sorry for bothering you guys.

Comment: no you bothered noone. any idea why it worked this way? and especially why simply leaving secure boot disabled couldn't work just as well? thanks in advance

Comment: With respect to Tatsu's response. Make your solution good to read for others that may encounter the same issue. And pictures would be helpful too.