# Dual booting ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, windows-10

Can I use the method mentioned on [this site](http://zornsoftware.codenature.info/blog/dual-boot-zorin-9-with-windows-8-1.html)?

For any dual booting any Linux distro?
It worked for Zorin but now I want to dual boot Ubuntu 16.04 with Windows 10.

Comment: You may find https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot useful

Answer (score 1):

> Can i use the method mentioned on the site

Yes. That blog post (Which describes the process for Zorin OS), and how to install on UEFI hardware can also be applied to Ubuntu, since Zorin OS is based on Ubuntu, and the installation process is the same.

You may want to chack out [How can I dual-boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu on a UEFI HP notebook?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/666631/how-can-i-dual-boot-windows-10-and-ubuntu-on-a-uefi-hp-notebook) if you have UEFI (New computers).

Answer (score 0):

That guide, for all intents and purposes, will work pretty well with Ubuntu, as Zorin is based on Ubuntu.

However, if you already have Zorin OS installed but want to switch to Ubuntu, it's much easier.

When you're going through your install procedure, make sure to select <kbd>Something else</kbd> when asked about partitioning. From there, select the partition that Zorin was installed on (ext4), and format it. Set the mount point to `/` and everything will work just fine.