# Ubuntu not showing upon 1st reboot after fresh dual boot install

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, uefi, windows-8

So, I just installed Ubuntu on my laptop and worked on it for about an hour, I switched to my Windows 10 dual boot to get some files and restarted the machine. Ubuntu wasn't showing up on the boot manager anymore. I already reinstalled it and ran boot repair, this is the log file:

http://paste2.org/AXBZ4Adm

I can only get it to run now on the live cd, can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to AU ! Can you confirm yr versions of Windows, Linux and whether you are dealing with UEFI/Legacy Bios+Secure Boot+GPT or  something else. Without that info, helping you is difficult. You can respond by editing your question above and notifying me with "@Cbhihe" in a simple comment below.

Comment: You need to boot into Windows from UEFI and turn off fast startup or the always on hibernation. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2324331&p=13488472#post13488472 Then since you have an Acer you need to set a supervisory password in UEFI and enable trust on the specific .efi files for shim & grub. See step 35 and later: http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot

Answer (score 0):

From yr log it seems that there is a conflict between the way you installed Ubuntu (as if yr existing hw context was BIOS-MBR) alongside a Windows 8 system that is UEFI-GPT based.

Your best solution, if yr install of Ubuntu is very recent and you have not invested hours and hours of configuration in it, would be to start again fresh from yr pre-installed Windows OS.

- get rid of Ubuntu
- make sure that Windows boots as before. If not, backup yr most recent Windows side data and restore Windows.
- boot from live Linux CD/DVD/USB drive and install Ubuntu anew, taking into consideration the fact that you are likely dealing with UEFI + Secure Boot + GPT on the preinstalled Windows' side. Many tutorials (e.g. [[1]](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/dual-boot-windows-8-ubuntu.html),[[2]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/666631/how-can-i-dual-boot-windows-10-and-ubuntu-on-a-uefi-hp-notebook),[[3]](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2147295)) can guide you through that type of installation.

You will certainly find help on AU to solve yr dual boot install trouble, but in my experience all what you need (and more in that department) is already available at ubuntuforums.org. The 3rd reference above is a good illustration of that.

HTH. Post yr feedback as a comment below if you have doubts or if you think my assumptions are misguided.

Comment: Hello, I solved this yesterday. I tried to use boot repair a few times and it wasn't working until I checked the option to "backup and rename EFI files". When I restarted it gave me a bios like message saying the boot wasn't working but after hiting enter 2 times I have grub with dual boot. Thanks!

Comment: +1 Somehow I still think you may have a system that is not correctly taking advantage of yr hardware (UEFI+GPT). It is yr choice naturally, but I, for one, would reinstall my OS. Good luck and thank you for the feedback.