# Installing Ubuntu on a 32gb Notebook with a failed Windows 10 Installation

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, usb, sd-card

I tried to update Windows 10 on a Toshiba Notebook, but after formatting the main Partition it just keeps going into a loop and won't install. The notebook only has 32gb max storage, so have decided I would like to run Ubuntu instead. I have downloaded the Ubuntu ISO on may main Laptop. I have a 32gb SD Card. How do I install Ubuntu either from  the SD Card or a USB Stick. My notebook does not have a CD drive. Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Enter the BIOS of your netbook and set it up to try to boot from USB first. Then use your USB drive to install Ubuntu. You can see instructions for that [there](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop).

If you encounter a problem make sure to note the error message. If googling doesn't find something mention it here (editing/updating your question) so we can help.

Regarding dual booting with Win 10 [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/666632/498541) answer may be of help.

Answer (score -1):

There is a tool calls "Startup Disk Creator", you just have to chose the Ubuntu ISO and the Pen Drive. Don't foget to download the most recent Ubuntu. http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu

Comment: OP didn't say he is running Ubuntu on the primary computer.