# I'm trying to play a game through playonlinux get an error

Tags: wine, games, playonlinux

I'm using ubuntu 16.04 and I'm trying to play league of legends but it isn't working. I just got ubuntu today so I'm really new to it. I've worked through numerous issues with wine but I'm tired and I can't find the answer to this one. I can post the full logs but i believe this is the problem.

> err:winediag:init_driver_info Invalid GPU override 1002:990f specified, ignoring.

Answer (score 1):

Playing Windows games on Ubuntu (or any Linux distribution) is not likely to work. Wine is a very poor Windows emulator and, as you've found out, is buggy as heck.

Your best bet for your Windows games that don't have a Linux port is a Windows machine. The best and simplest way to do that if you want to keep Ubuntu for other things is a dual-boot system, where you would either:

- split your hard drive into 2 partitions, 1 for Ubuntu and 1 for Windows
- or get a 2nd hard drive, keep one for Ubuntu use the other for Windows (my preferred option)

Ubuntu comes with a boot manager called GRUB that will pop-up a menu every time you boot to allow you to choose which OS you want to boot (Ubuntu or Windows).

Comment: Here is a link to a AskUbuntu answer showing how to do dual boot (pretty recent, covers Win10 and Secure UEFI): http://askubuntu.com/a/666632/175503

Comment: That's preposterous, there are literally _thousands_ of games and applications running _flawlessly_ on Wine.

Answer (score 1):

League of Legends works perfectly well on Wine. You can check program compatibility by searching in the Wine AppDB: https://appdb.winehq.org/

In order to run games on Linux, I recommend installing Playonlinux, a user interface for Wine that has a database of games and applications for which all you need to do is run an install wizard, and it takes care of all necessary configurations. If you're on an Ubuntu system simply open a terminal and run `sudo apt install playonlinux`.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  The OP says that he already is trying to run through playonlinux.