# Windows 10, dual boot Ubuntu, error "system doesn't have any USB boot option..."

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb

I've been trying to dual boot Ubuntu with Windows 10 on my laptop (Acer Aspire s).
Whenever i try and boot from a USB i get an error saying "System doesn't have any USB boot option. Please select other boot option in boot manager menu" and then takes me to a menu where i can choose Windows 10 or Linpus Lite.

As an experiment i tried booting a DVD instead (without connecting any DVD reader, my laptop doesn't have a DVD reader either) and it gave me the same error, except it said "... DVD boot ...".
Does anyone have any idea why this is happening and also any solutions so i can get Ubuntu installed?

I've now also tried to turn of secure boot which didn't help.
After that i tried going to Legacy mode, which did seem to work. But then the laptop didn't recognize windows and could only boot into Ubuntu. If i then tried to install Ubuntu it again wouldn't recognize Windows on the SSD. And since i'm inexperienced with this kind of thing i didn't wanna take the chance and try to install Ubuntu.

Comment: Have you reviewed http://askubuntu.com/questions/666631/how-can-i-dual-boot-windows-10-and-ubuntu-on-a-uefi-hp-notebook I realize this is supposedly specific to an HP but it's well explained and the solution should have much in common.

Comment: That link doesn't seem to cover my situation. I'm not trying to change my boot order, nor am i looking for a guide to install Ubuntu. I'm looking for a solution the the error i get when i try and boot Ubuntu from a USB. And also if the error is unsolvable, then how else i can install Ubuntu alongside Windows.

Comment: Some systems particularly with UEFI Secure boot on, require another setting to allow use of USB ports or allow booting from USB ports. May also have UEFI boot from USB ports settings. Check your UEFI. Most Acer are similar: Acer Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot

Comment: I'm sorry you feel that the link I provided doesn't cover your situation. With no feedback regarding what happened when you tried (if you did) there's nothing else I can do for you. Perhaps you'll have better luck if you try the link offered by @oldfred