# How to boot to ubuntu not windows after instal?

Tags: boot, partitioning, windows

So I am new to Linux and decided to give ubuntu a shot. So I made a USB stick with ubuntu and booted from it and then installed it on a 100gb partition on my hdd. Now windows is installed on my ssd so it is completely separate from ubuntu. The problem is now that I can't boot to ubuntu after the instal I don't have any prompt on boot to choose between it and windows. I changed the boot prioritys so the hdd is first and got rid of the ssd completely but it still boots to windows. I'm obviously missing something if Anybody has any help that would be greatly appreciated and thanks.

Comment: Refer to... http://www.howtogeek.com/187789/dual-booting-explained-how-you-can-have-multiple-operating-systems-on-your-computer/ The answer is the third heading from the top.

Answer (score 0):

This Question has already been answered e.g. here asuming you are using windows 8 or 10
[How can I dual-boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu on a UEFI HP notebook?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/666631/how-can-i-dual-boot-windows-10-and-ubuntu-on-a-uefi-hp-notebook)
The Post is too long to repeat a short answer here but usually the problem is in the windows boot setups