# No grub screen after installing Ubuntu 14.04 alongside Windows 10

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

I have a PC with Windows 10 and I need to install Ubuntu 14.04 alongside it. I followed the exact same steps I found online and yet, after installing Ubuntu, the computer boots directly into Windows 10. Here is what I did:

1. Downloaded the ISO of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
2. Put said ISO onto a USB drive with Rufus
3. Deallocated 60 GB from my C: HDD (I only have a 1TB HDD, no SSD). So far, so good.
4. Disabled fast startup
5. Restart into the UEFI system, boot from device
6. at this point, aside from the CD/DVD boot option, I see a "LINPUS LITE USB" and "EFI USB BOOT". If I choose the latter, a screen appears saying that there is no bootable USB device, then redirects me to a screen where I can choose between Windows 10 and, again, Linpus Lite. I pick Linpus Lite and it finally boot into Ubuntu
7. I select "try Ubuntu", proceed to install and restart the computer.

At this point, I have no way to boot into Ubuntu. It goes straight to Windows 10 and, even in the boot menu of the UEFI screen, I have no option whatsoever that allows me into the Ubuntu partition. I even tried to install the boot repair but "cannot locate package". 
What went wrong? Why isn't the grub appearing? I also tried disabling the Secure Boot but nothing changed.

Comment: I think explained much better in [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/666631/how-can-i-dual-boot-windows-10-and-ubuntu-on-a-uefi-hp-notebook) post.

Comment: Thanks, I read that but I was really hoping to not having to install Ubuntu first. I already have Windows installed and I see no reason to remove it and install all over again. I was wondering if there was a way to just install Ubuntu alongside