# Full screen errors: dual-boot system Windows10 and Ubuntu16.04 with UEFI BIOS

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, uefi, live-usb, windows-10

I want to install Ubuntu1604 on my computer, but when I click "Install Ubuntu", it gives full screen errors.

============================**Before installation**======================

1.Windows10 installed already -> (so I guess)I am using UEFI BIOS

2.Disk partioning: One 500 MB system reserved partition; The rest is the other partition(about 450GB).

3.Boot\CSM(Compatibility Support Module):

- Boot from storage Devices = UEFI driver first;
- Boot Device Control = UEFI and Legacy OPROM;
- Fast Boot = disabled;

4.Boot

- Sequere Boot

  1. option 1 = UEFI SanDisk blablabla(This is the Ubuntu1604 iso USB)
  2. option 2 = blablabla(This is Windows10)
  3. option 3 = disabled
  4. option 4 = disabled

=============================**Install Ubuntu**=========================

Restart computer;

Wait 5 seconds, without click any F2, DEL button.

I go into the black color page for installing Ubuntu

1. install ubuntu
2. check disk defects
3. do not remember what is writing here.....

And I click on install ubuntu, it gives me full screen error..

I don't know where is the problem.

**Maybe the ubuntu1604 iso should be burned in UEFI mode from rufus?**

I am pretty sure the iso is not in UEFI mode, but I really don't know whether the iso file matter at all.

Here is the link to create a UEFI bootable USB.

https://www.vanstechelman.eu/content/creating-an-uefi-bootable-linux-usb-stick

Here are the documents or links I have read through already, please check and then answer my question(I already works on these links like 6 hours.)

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

[How can I dual-boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu on a UEFI HP notebook?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/666631/how-can-i-dual-boot-windows-10-and-ubuntu-on-a-uefi-hp-notebook)

Thanks for your time.

Best,
Yumin

Comment: did you install ubuntu in EFI mode? does the EFI firmware support OS boot selection?

Comment: I do not understand your answer. That is actually my question, I am pretty sure the iso is not UEFI mode, but I don't know whether the ubuntu iso in UEFI mode has impact or not. And about your second question, I really don't understand it, I am a newie.

Or.... what your first question means? You want to ask me whether I am under UEFI BIOS to boot the Ubuntu? I think so. Well...but how could I prove I am using UEFI BIOS?

Comment: if Windows 10 came preinstalled then it is probably in EFI mode, thus Ubuntu needs to be installed in EFI mode so grub can launch both Windows and Ubuntu.

Comment: How could I prove I am using UEFI mode?

Comment: turn off CSM in the firmware settings

Comment: Boot\CSM(Compatibility Support Module):

Boot from storage Devices = UEFI driver first;
Boot Device Control = UEFI and Legacy OPROM;
Fast Boot = disabled;

Comment: set it to UEFI only