# How do I install Windows alongside Ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, windows

*This is not a duplicate of [How can I dual-boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu on a UEFI HP notebook?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/666631) because I have Ubuntu installed already while the other post asks about having Windows installed first.*

I currently have Ubuntu 16.04.2 installed on my laptop, and I would like to dual-boot with Windows.  How would I go about doing that?  If it helps, here is a screenshot of my hard drive listed in **Disks**.

[image: 1.0 TB Disk -- /dev/nvme0n1]

P.S.  I won't have my copy of Windows until later today, so I may not respond immediately.

Comment: If you have the chance its, in general, easier to install Windows first and then Ubuntu.

Comment: @M.Becerra: [not necessarily for an UEFI system](https://askubuntu.com/a/666632/3940)

Comment: @M.Becerra Yes I know that, but I would rather not have to re-install Ubuntu.

Comment: The above considers UEFI installation, the one you should have done from the start with Ubuntu (also the recommended mode for any Windows 8 or newer). But instead you installed Ubuntu in Legacy mode. It will be much easier to install both in the recommended method. As it is now you'll have an hard time making room for Windows and then reinstalling Grub.