# Dual boot on 250gb SSD (Ubuntu and Windows)

Tags: dual-boot

I just upgraded from HDD to SSD and I'm planning to do a dual boot in my machine. Is it possible to do it in a 256gb SSD? What is the best strategy partitioning for this?

- **Windows:** (planned to install applications) Adobe applications
  (Editing) Microsoft Office
- **Ubuntu:**  Mostly applications needed for web development e.g apache,
  sublime

For movies and data, I have an external drive.

Comment: 100GB for Windows 10 + rest of partitions made by Windows installer, around 50GB for Ubuntu on '/' mount point + 5GB swap if needed if You have 8GB ram...rest GBs for additional NTFS partition, I would do like that...or around 20GB for Ubuntu on '/' mount point and 20~30GB for '/home' partition for Ubuntu

Comment: @PawelG do i need to create a swap partition? I have 8gb ram.

Comment: I have a DELL i7 with 250Gb SSD and 16 Gb of RAM, I just installed Windows 10 alongside with Ubuntu 18.04 two days ago, Until now everything is working smoothly, I followed the instructions in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/666632/408473) it's quite long but it worth the read. Concerning your the swap, I used 4Gb swap space, check out [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/49138/408473) for more details.

Comment: @John Kenneth de Lara I've used Ubuntu only on '/' mount point 50GB partition with and without swap having 8GB RAM, both options with no any issues hence now I use swap 5.5GB just in case as I do some works in Blender with 3d scenes. Surely for casual use You may be fine only with one partition ext4 for all Ubuntu. Good luck :-)

Comment: With 18.04 default installer, it only creates / (root). It now uses a swapfile. If you already have a swap partition, then it will use that instead. Swapfile is 2GB which I suggest for a swap partition as with SSD you do not need nor want to hibernate anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible.
If you have already migrated or installed windows on SSD, try to shrink windows partition to maybe half of disk size or what size you prefer.
I did it like: 
100GB Win10
100 GB Linux mint ( based on ubuntu) 
and about 40GB Unallocated

After shrinking just burn ISO, boot from it and run installer. When it asks if you want to install it next to win or format disc, click to Install ubuntu next to... 
If you want to partition it yourself just press something else. you need ext4 partition for / (root) 
i prefer ext2 partition mounted to /boot ( about 1GB). If You're running on UEFI, just add EFI partition same size as /boot.

Click install.
After installation simply reboot your pc and enjoy.

Comment: @Reneckk do i need to create a swap partition? I have 8gb ram.

Comment: You do not need it because you will reduce ssd lifetime.  8 GB is a lot of memory. I personally do not recommend it