# Forcing Ubuntu 16.04 installation UEFI mode

Tags: boot, uefi

I have an unattended Ubuntu 16.04 installation that i created using [this](http://gyk.lt/ubuntu-16-04-desktop-unattended-installation/) guide

The installation works great, however it is installing to BIOS MBR and I'd like it use UEFI instead

What component/config decides whether if to use BIOS/UEFI
How do I make this installation to install Ubuntu in UEFI mode?

Moshe

Comment: It is how you boot from UEFI boot menu. UEFI and BIOS are not compatible so once you start booting in one mode you cannot switch. You may also have to change UEFI settings to turn on or allow UEFI boot and allow USB boot. You may or may not want UEFI Secure Boot on. Shows install with screen shots. Both BIOS purple accessibility screen & UEFI black grub menu screen
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: What is the make/model of your hardware? Making a dual-boot or stand alone  system with [HP] (possibly others) ... this may help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/666631/how-can-i-dual-boot-windows-10-and-ubuntu-on-a-uefi-hp-notebook If a UEFI machine has previously installed an operating system (such as windows), remnants of the old grub may be still be present. Special steps will need to be taken to use UEFI with the new OS install and/or remove/update the new secureboot grub.