# Grub not finding windows

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, ssd

Having issues getting Grub to recognise my windows drive.

I followed a guide which gave a step by step on how to have Windows and Ubuntu on two separate SSDs.

It pretty much went like this.

```
Install windows on ssd1

Disconnect windows drive and install ubuntu on ssd2

Boot into new ubuntu with windows drive connected and sudo update-grub
```

Done.

Except, here I am many hours later and I'm not done.

Sudo update-grub doesn't show a windows boot manager. Sudo os-prober doesn't show anything at all. I can see the drive with Windows on it in the Ubuntu file explorer. I can go into every folder except the windows one. (Not sure if this is a permissions issue or something? I don't use bitlocker so I don't think this is an encryption thing)

I've been messing around with this for ages now and I really have no idea what to do. I can smash F11 a million times when booting and choose Windows/Linux drives but I cannot get Grub to pick it up.

Any suggestions? (and if it wasn't already obvious I'm very new to this so -50 Int for suggestions haha) Thanks :)

Comment: When I had similar troubles I found the following helpful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/666631/how-can-i-dual-boot-windows-10-and-ubuntu-on-a-uefi-hp-notebook

Comment: Are both installed in UEFI boot mode? You may want to turn fast boot off in UEFI as less until it works correctly as that gives more time to press UEFI boot key. Or is Windows fast start up not off? http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions

Comment: My drive isn't found when I turn switch from Legacy+UEFI to just UEFI. So I assume it isn't. Is there any way to go about changing that?

Okay, I just checked it's in Legacy mode. Using W+R Msinfo32.

Currently searching around for a guide on how to change to UEFI.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by re-installing windows on GPT SSD in UEFI mode.

And my BIOS was automatically disabling windows boot manager when I installed linux on drive #2. So re-enabling that basically fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well first thing first do trouble shooting on the windows drive. If grub isn't seeing the windows boot loader.... is it there.

Can you boot to just the windows drive? select the windows drive as the primary boot drive and see what happens. If that doesn't work remove the Ubuntu drive and do a boot with just the windows drive.

If your windows doesn't boot then you found the source of the error. If it does boot then your very strange idea of removing disks flopped. You should have left in both drives and installed Ubuntu and grub onto either the primary or secondary disk reflecting your preference for environment.

Comment: I can boot into the windows drive. Weird thing is, I can only do this from the boot menu & only when Legacy + UEFI is on. I can't go into the BIOS and set this windows drive as highest priority. It doesn't appear.

The removing disk idea wasn't mine, it was a guide I found on here.