# Windows 10 is not booting after installing ubuntu alongside

Tags: grub2, bootloader

I am new to this and was curious about running Ubuntu on my laptop running windows 10..

I couldn't not find the Grub menu after installing ubuntu so I went back into windows and found a so called hack...https://askubuntu.com/a/816347/970928

After doing following the steps I used ubuntu successfully from the Grub2 menu , now I wanna go back to windows but whenever I enter the Grub menu and select the option :

windows boot manager (on dev/sda1)

It opens the Grub menu again and again!!

What can I do to fix this guy's?

Comment: Years ago we suggested that fix of renaming grub to be Windows boot file. Many other work arounds.  Grub only boots working Windows, and Windows turn fast start up with updates and the grub will not boot it. May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: Thanks guys!@karel & oldfred... boot-repair did the trick... works like a charm!