# Windows10 wouldn't Boot in GRUB Ubuntu Dual boot

Tags: boot, 16.04, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I've Installed Ubuntu in dual boot with Windows10 and at first I had a problem with GRUB not showing at startup but I solved it with renaming files in Windows with help of this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/666631/how-to-get-grub-to-be-the-default-bootloader-instead-of-windows-boot-manager-on).

Now  works at startup and shows me these options:

[image: GRUB]

But when I select 'Windows Boot Manager (on `/dev/sda2`)', Timer below just resets and GRUB reappears, it doesn't let me boot into Windows.

But I can boot Windows if I select 'Windows Boot UEFI Loader' (Option 4 in above image).

Is there any problem here? Is this supposed to work like this? According to me it should load into Windows with Windows Boot Manager but it doesn't.
What should I do?

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

no issue here.

> Windows UEFI bootmgfw.efi

and

> Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sda2)

are deprecated leftovers from file renaming.

The correct option is :

> Windows Boot UEFI Loader

You can clean up and reorder your grub using this tool : [grub customiser](https://launchpad.net/~danielrichter2007/+archive/ubuntu/grub-customizer).

or completely reset your grub using ths tool [boot repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

I personally recommend installing both just in case but only using grub customizer to remove the extra windows entries.

Comment: Thank You Soo Much! What will Boot Repair do? Will it affect my windows file renaming? Whats the use of it?

Comment: Welcome! boot repair is mainly used from the USB live ubuntu installer to remove and replace grub when it has an issue (been removed by windows install...) it's cool feature is that whatver issue booting you have before it's almost guaranteed to fix it. it also is better at detecting and adding windows to the grub than ubuntu. and yes when you run it, it will delete all the grub modifications you made. but you can always redo them. if your question is, whether you won't be able to boot to windows after running it, the answer is no, you'll definitely be able to boot to windows after running it.

Comment: ok. Thanks for making things easy for me. @tatsu

Comment: no problem! glad to help :)