# Can't install ubuntu from a bootable usb

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

Currently I have on my laptop 2 hard drives. 1 hdd with 1tb of size and 1 ssd with 250gb. I had windows 10 and ubuntu working on the same hdd until I installed the ssd. When I installed it, tried to clone ubuntu but gave me some problems so I deleted ubuntu partitions from both hard drives. So currently I only have the hdd with windows 10. 
The problem comes when I tried to install Ubuntu in the ssd from a bootable usb. I have this messages and the installation doesn't start o if it starts, stops with the same messages.
http://prntscr.com/qv8uxq http://prntscr.com/qv8v57

Comment: What brand/model system? What video card/chip? Are you using nomodeset boot parameter and UEFI boot?https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it &  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: This is my laptop HP Pavilion 17-ab004ns. And yes I use UEFI mode.

Comment: HP is not particularly friendly to dual boot Ubuntu. You must update UEFI & SSD firmware. Some then say you can only from within UEFI change boot order to boot Ubuntu. Or always manually select from UEFI boot menu. HP Pavillion X360 13-a220nw
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2359510 & 
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1858477#p1858477 & http://askubuntu.com/questions/666631/how-can-i-dual-boot-windows-10-and-ubuntu-on-a-uefi-hp-notebook

Comment: I havent any problem untill now that removed the partitions to reinstall ubuntu. The first time was fine and even reinstalled it 3 times, all before I installed it on the ssd.

Comment: Did you update UEFI and SSD firmware? My new SSD has an ISO that is like a live installer, but only does UEFI update. Every brand is a bit different on how you can update it, but most offer another way than just in Windows.

Comment: I tried to update the ssd firmware but following the tutorial that crucial made, dont make the usb bootable so I cannot now if is updated. By the way, I guess the problem is that maybe the loop0 in ubuntu is missed (but don't know if is it related to this because I deleted that partition). This meesage appear meanwhile I try to install ubuntu: can not mount /dev/loop0

Comment: In the installed system, the loop devices are related to snaps. I uninstall snaps and just use .deb installed from synaptic or command line. Is this from the live installer. If it got corrupted during install, somehow you may need to remake it.