# will resetting windows remove GRUB and Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows, reset

I am currently dual booting Ubuntu alongside Windows, with both installations being on the same hard drive, just different partitions, and I boot with GRUB. I want to reset windows, through settings with remove all files, but will this also remove GRUB and ubuntu? as I would like to keep them both, so i can continue dual booting, but start with a clean slate on Windows, still keeping everything in tact on ubuntu and the linux side of things.

TL;DR: can i reset windows but keep my ubuntu installation and GRUB?

Comment: I see the UEFI tag, so you are affirmative about that it's not a legacy MBR boot schema? It's UEFI, is it?

Comment: @Levente ``/sys/firmware/efi`` is present, so yes, I am using UEFI

Comment: A reset of Windows will not delete other partitions. I guess though it will make Windows boot loader your main loader again. That is no problem. Run the Live Environment and make Grub the default loader again. See for example: https://askubuntu.com/questions/666631/how-to-get-grub-to-be-the-default-bootloader-instead-of-windows-boot-manager-on-a-UEFI-laptop or search for 'how to make grub default bootloader'.

Comment: When I need to do something, I just do it. You gave no specifics as to what Ubuntu you're talking about, thus I can only be generic. In almost all cases you can correct whatever is lost during re-installs, but even if you can't; you can re-install a Ubuntu Desktop system without any loss of data, and have the *manually installed* packages you added post-install auto re-install (where from Ubuntu repositories) so non-destructive re-install is usually done in ~15 minutes anyway; but that's only ever the fallback if it can't be fixed.  Your question answer is YES, but clean/fix up maybe required.

Comment: Installing windows will overwrite grub. You will need to reinstall grub through a live usb stick running linux. You can use the [grub-install](https://www.fosslinux.com/4477/how-to-repair-the-grub-bootloader-using-a-ubuntu-live-usb-drive.htm) command for the terminal approach of reinstalling grub or the graphical way using the [boot repair app](https://linuxhint.com/ubuntu_boot_repair_tutorial/). Reinstalling grub will not mess with your Ubuntu install though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)