# Having trouble installing ubuntu alongside windows 10

Tags: boot, partitioning, windows, bootloader

I want to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10, but I keep running into trouble.

First I tried to create a bootable USB drive, to test Ubuntu, and then install it. While creating the bootable drive went just fine , but  booting from it didn't: [image]

So, I searched for a way to install Ubuntu without a cd/usb drive, and found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/484434/install-ubuntu-without-cd-and-usb-how) (first answer).

That worked, and I chose "Try Ubuntu", to see if everything was working. It was, so I installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 10. I had previously set up 100 GB of unallocated space, because I was told Ubuntu would format it and use it.

After the installation was done I rebooted, but there wasn't a boot option for Ubuntu. The only options were Windows 10 and Unetbootin, the same as before I installed Ubuntu.

I checked if Unetbootin would maybe just boot straight to the freshly installed Ubuntu, but I was just presented with the same options as before ("install ubuntu" and "try without installing").

So I booted Windows, to see if Ubuntu had taken up the previously unallocated space of 100 GB. [image] The stuff I marked with red was previously 100 GB of unallocated space. Now it's 2 partitions that I can't access with Windows, so Ubuntu must be installed on there, right?

If I'm not wrong, that means Ubuntu is actually installed, I just can't boot to it for some reason. I have been looking through the boot options on my motherboard, but can't find an option to boot to ubuntu. But I found out that my printer is listed as a boot option lol.
Also: for some reason Windows Defender has  now blocked me from using Unetbootin.exe... No idea why

If you know what I need to do in order to solve this mess it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [USB device not accepting address](http://askubuntu.com/questions/117524/usb-device-not-accepting-address)

Comment: What brand/model computer. You may just need to go into UEFI and select Ubuntu. Did you use UEFI to boot installer and then it installs in UEFI boot mode? Some computers UEFI is hard coded to only boot Windows, so a work around is required. But may be best to see details:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Answer (score 0):

Check your BIOS or UEFI settings. Sometimes a UEFI is out of date and needs to be updated. Or you could use the legacy BIOS setting. The problem is somewhere in your BIOS or UEFI settings.

See the other post on this similar issue [Dual boot Ubuntu (14.04) with Windows 10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/577481/dual-boot-ubuntu-14-04-with-windows-10)

Answer (score 0):

For windows defender: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/turn-windows-defender-on-off#turn-windows-defender-on-off=windows-7

You will also need to search for UEFI and enable boot from usb as your default boot drive.

I gather unetbootin is an alternative to grub.  Maybe you could install the iso from a usb stick(drive, or whatever) after you make changes to your UEFI (successor to the BIOS).  Dig around in the new BIOS, see what is there, google ...er search away for anything you don't understand and then read up on how to install ubuntu.